# Tech Leader or Tech Lead

Tags: difference

In the technology field we constantly see the terms "Tech Leader" or "Tech Lead", as if there was no difference between them.

I assume that the term "Tech Lead" is correct, as I see it everywhere, but it makes no sense to me, once "lead" is a verb as in "to lead". So in this case the correct one should be "Tech Leader", because "leader" is an adjective.

I appreciate if someone could explain it to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience as an engineer in Silicon Valley,

a "technology leader" is a company or a person who has an understanding of technology that "leads" other companies or people in the sense of being more advanced;

and a "tech lead" is a person who has the job of leading (managing or coordinating) the technology aspects of a project at a company.

The second usage is consistent with definition 30 of *lead* at [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/lead?s=t),

> 30. a person or thing that leads.

As a comment, when you said,

> So in this case the correct one should be "Tech Leader", because "leader" is an adjective.

*Leader* is a noun in this case, not an adjective. I don't know of any adjective usage of *leader*.

Comment: It is great to have that clarified, thanks. As for your comment in the end, you're right, leader is not an adjective, my mistake.